# Реализация функций empty и clear для вектора

Tags: c++

Правильно я сделала  функции?

```
  template<typename T>
  bool Vector<T>::Empty() const
  {
     return (mSize == mCapacity);
  }

  template<typename T>
  void Vector<T>::Clear()
   {
      mVector[mSize].~T();
      mSize = 0;
   }
```

Переделала

```
 template<typename T>
 void Vector<T>::Clear()
 {
    for (decltype(mSize) i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
       mVector[i].~T();
    mSize = 0;
 }
```

Comment: @gil9red то что вы изменили  правильно  будет работать??

Comment: Код не менял, только заголовок вопроса

Comment: @gil9red    ок. я  поняла. А я  правильно переделала?

Comment: Давно с с++ работал, но не думаю что вручную вызывать деструктор идея хорошая. Смотрите в ответе к вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Нет.

Пустой - это когда в нем нет элементов. т.е.

```
return mSize==0;
```

Ну, а очистка... Опять же, зависит от того, как именно у вас реализовано удаление и добавление элементов. Но по сути это - `pop_back()`, выполненное `mSize` раз. Исходите из этого.

Comment: так у меня  на вход ничего не принимает pop_back, как мне указать чтобы  для выполняло  mSize раз? фором пройтись?

Comment: Просто `mSize=0;`. Если нужно удалять элементы деструктором - то соответственно перед этим небольшой цикл с удалением всех элементов.